# Faking a MediaRequest and Media Items

Tags: media-library, unit-testing, fakedb

I am currently trying to mock a media request and the media item I am requesting using FakeDb but for some reason my request is returning an empty MediaPath rather than the MediaPath I am expecting.

Here is the method:

```
public class RequestMediaEXT
{
    public bool getImage(HttpContext context)
    {
        MediaRequest request = MediaManager.ParseMediaRequest(context.Request);
        string mediaPath = request?.MediaUri.MediaPath;
        if (mediaPath == null | MediaPath == string.empty)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Unit test for the method:

```
[Theory]
[CustomAutoData("http://image.here/", "~/media/myimage.ashx")]
public void getImage_imageFound_ReturnsTrue(string url, string media)
{

    string myImageUrl = url + media;
    Sitecore.Data.ID mediaItemId = Sitecore.Data.ID.NewID;

    HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, myImageUrl, string.Empty);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
    HttpContext httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    var processor = new RequestMediaEXT()

    // create some media item. Location, fields and template are not important
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        var mediaFakeItem = new DbItem("myimage")
        {
            ParentID = Sitecore.ItemIDs.MediaLibraryRoot
        };
        mediaFakeItem.FullPath = myImageUrl;
        db.Add(mediaFakeItem);

        // create media provider mock and configure behaviour
        MediaProvider mediaProvider =
            Substitute.For<MediaProvider>();

        mediaProvider
            .GetMediaUrl(Arg.Is<Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem>(i => i.ID == mediaItemId))
            .Returns(myImageUrl);

        // substitute the original provider with the mocked one
        using (new Sitecore.FakeDb.Resources.Media.MediaProviderSwitcher(mediaProvider))
        {
            //Act
            processor.getImage(httpContext);

            //Assert
            Assert.False(!processor.getImage(httpContext));
        }
    }
}
```

How do I mock the HttpContext such that the MediaPath doesn't become an empty string but the actual MediaPath?

I am using Sitecore 8.1 and therefore have to use the now obsolete MediaProviderSwitcher.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is not Unit Testing, I would consider it more of an integration test, I am a broken record on this subject but it is my opinion that you should reserve unit testing for testing functionality you own and take advantage of focused and mockable interfaces, see [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Mocking the HttpContext almost always ends in tears byways of a test maintenance nightmare, however, there is some relief to this from ASP.NET 3.5 and up; look at using HttpContextBase and HttpContextWrapper.

```
public bool getImage(HttpContextBase context)
{
    ...
}
```

HttpContextBase is abstract and you will have an easier time mocking it. When you need to adapt the HttpContext you can with the HttpContextWrapper class.

```
var abstractContext = new HttpContextWrapper(context);
```